# Converting Serial data format using python

Tags: python, serialization

I am new to python,currently working on the project reading serial port from micro controller to capture sensor data. The serial data i received looks like this:

`[5;17H  0.029[5;40H  0.736[5;63H  9.557[7;17H  0.038[7;40H  0.001    [7;63H  0.008[9;17H-34.199[9;40H 25.800[9;63H 13.799[14;17H -4.623[14;40H  0.597[14;63H218.920[19;14H`

this serial data actually have escape sequence 'x1b' before open bracket. How do i get rid of them, escape sequence and text format(5;17H..) and just print sensor data x,y,z format line by line. Can somebody help me.. Thank you..

I'm using python serial code:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('COM9', 115200, bytesize=8, timeout=0)

while True:
  data = ser.read(size=8).decode("utf-8")
  s = str(data)
  print(data)

ser.close()
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: I figure it out using str.strip, split but none is workable. will try using regex.. but not sure to read encoding utf-8 format or not. what is the best solution to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Sensor data record starts with `\033`, so split at this for instance:

```
data_list = data.split('\033')
for v in data:
    print (v)
```

Comment: nope,the sensor data record is between [5;17H and \x1b (escape char). I did try on data.split but it print ['63H211.']['5']['52\x1b', '19;'] .. it split the sensor data character together...

Comment: **UARTprintf("\033[5;17H%3d.%03d", i32IPart[0], i32FPart[0]); UARTprintf("\033[5;40H%3d.%03d", i32IPart[1], i32FPart[1]); UARTprintf("\033[5;63H%3d.%03d", i32IPart[2], i32FPart[2]);** This is sample c++ code print data from microcontroller.

Comment: Updated my Answer to handle `\033`.